# Merge two rows in same table while summing a column

Tags: postgresql

With the risk of not fully understanding PostgresQL, here goes:

I have a table called `work`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE work(
    name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    round bigint NOT NULL,
    amount bigint,

    PRIMARY KEY (name, round)
)
```

New rows are added where each name can have multiple rounds. Round 0 has special meaning in my application.

Sometimes, a specific round needs to be merged back into round 0. Round 0 might exist, but could also not exist yet. So, with the following data:

| name | round | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 300 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 |
| 2 | 0 | 500 |
| 2 | 3 | 1500 |
| 1 | 6 | 200 |
| 1 | 9 | 200 |
| 2 | 6 | 50 |
| 2 | 9 | 75 |

*(ordering not as it should be to make it more clear)*

all rows with round 3 need to merge with rows with round 0, summing the amount and keeping the other rounds (6, 9) intact. In the end, all rows with round 3 need to be removed from the table, leaving only

| name | round | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 400 |
| 2 | 0 | 2000 |
| 1 | 6 | 200 |
| 1 | 9 | 200 |
| 2 | 6 | 50 |
| 2 | 9 | 75 |

To be clear, I don't need a SELECT statement, but I need this written in the database.

What I came up with

```sql
WITH round_to_move AS (
    SELECT name, round, amount 
    FROM work 
    WHERE name = $1 AND round = $2
)
INSERT INTO work (name, round, work)
SELECT name, 0, amount 
FROM round_to_move
ON CONFLICT (name, round)
DO UPDATE SET amount = work.amount + EXCLUDED.amount
```

but this doesn't delete the existing row.

So, what I'm looking for is a sort-of UPDATE statement with GROUP BY and SUM() but I can't figure that out.

Comment: I am not seeing how your query would work: 1) I don't see where the column `work` is coming from? 2) The `SELECT name, 0, amount, work... 1` is four values that you are trying to insert into three columns `(name, round, work)`.

Comment: I simplified my example, I forgot to remove that fourth argument so you can ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Make the INSERT another CTE query and then DELETE at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE work(
    name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    round bigint NOT NULL,
    amount bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, round)
);
INSERT INTO work values (1,0 ,300),
(1 ,3 ,100),
(2 ,0 ,500),
(2 ,3 ,1500),
(1 ,6 ,200),
(1 ,9 ,200),
(2 ,6 ,50),
(2 ,9 ,75);

 select * from work;
 name | round | amount 
------+-------+--------
 1    |     0 |    300
 1    |     3 |    100
 2    |     0 |    500
 2    |     3 |   1500
 1    |     6 |    200
 1    |     9 |    200
 2    |     6 |     50
 2    |     9 |     75

WITH round_to_move AS (
    SELECT name, round, amount 
    FROM work 
    WHERE name = '1' AND round = 3
),
ins as (INSERT INTO work (name, round, amount)
SELECT name, 0, amount
FROM round_to_move
ON CONFLICT (name, round)
DO UPDATE SET amount = work.amount::integer + EXCLUDED.amount)
delete from 
   work using round_to_move 
where 
   work.name = round_to_move.name 
and 
   work.round = round_to_move.round;

select * from work; 
 name | round | amount 
------+-------+--------
 2    |     0 |    500
 2    |     3 |   1500
 1    |     6 |    200
 1    |     9 |    200
 2    |     6 |     50
 2    |     9 |     75
 1    |     0 |    400
```